Why does ESLint complain about the general object type?
I have a common type OptionPanel for three types InputOptionPanel, SelectOptionPanel, CalcOptionPanel:
export interface InputOptionPanelBase {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  required: boolean;
  value: string;
  group: string;
  title: string;
  optionGroup_id: string | undefined;
  position: number;
  editable: boolean;
  description?: string | null;
}

type InputOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: 'input' };
type SelectOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: 'select'; list: ISelectListItem[] };
type CalcOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: 'calc'; calc: Calc };

export type OptionPanel = InputOptionPanel | SelectOptionPanel | CalcOptionPanel;

Why does an error occur when declaring an object?

First error const newOption: OptionPanel - Property "calc" is missing in type OptionPanel and is required in type CalcOptionPanel
Second error
newOption.list = optionLists[option_id].map((listItem_id) => {
          const listItemDB = list.find((listItem) => listItem._id === listItem_id)!;
          return {
            title: getTextFromTitle(listItemDB.title),
            value: listItem_id,
            _id: listItem_id,
          };
        });

Property "list" does not exist on type "OptionPanel".
Property "list" does not exist on type "InputOptionPanel".
I can't understand why these errors appear if I have a generic type? Which can be one of three types.
export type OptionPanel = InputOptionPanel | SelectOptionPanel | CalcOptionPanel;

In the first error, the "calc" property is missing from the InputOptionPanel and SelectOptionPanel types.
In the second error, the property "list" is missing in the types InputOptionPanel and CalcOptionPanel
It seems to me that this error is due to the following type creation:
type InputOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: 'input' };
    type SelectOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: 'select'; list: ISelectListItem[] };
    type CalcOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: 'calc'; calc: Calc };


It's because in SelectOptionPanel and CalcOptionPanel you have calc and list properties which are required. so when you are declaring a new object ts doesn't know that your type is input or calc or select.
so you are receiving an error because if type is equal to calc you need to pass calc field to the object and if your type is select you need to pass list field.
if you want to solve this you need to check the condition on type variable before declaring your object so ts can recognize the right type. i suggest you something like this:
enum MyTypes {
  input = 'input',
  select = 'select',
  calc = 'calc'
}
type InputOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: Test.input };
type SelectOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: Test.select; list: ISelectListItem[] };
type CalcOptionPanel = InputOptionPanelBase & { type: Test.calc; calc: Calc};

export type OptionPanel = InputOptionPanel | CalcOptionPanel | SelectOptionPanel;

// declaring object for each type
if (type === MyTypes.select) {
  // your type is SelectOptionPanel and you need to define list property too
  const newOption: OptionPanel = {
    type, otherProperties, list: optionLists.map(yourMap)
}
}


Thank you very much. The fact is that when the newOption object is declared, it does not correspond to one of the types. Because in order for it to correspond to SelectOptionPanel it must have a list property and type: 'select', to correspond to CalcOptionPanel it must have a calc property and type: 'calc', to match the InputOptionPanel type it must have type: 'input'. What's in my code? My newOption object has a type property that is not exactly defined, if I set it to type : 'input' the error goes away because now it corresponds to one of the types (InputOptionPanel)
